# How to define a non ISO date parser in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, date

I need to parse strings like "28-05-2014_02:44:32.630" from the Pandas lib.

The following code works like a charm with standard ISO date "28-05-2014T02:44:32.630":

```
In [1]: import dateutil.parser

In [3]: dateutil.parser.parse("28-05-2014T02:44:32.630", dayfirst=True)
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 28, 2, 44, 32, 630000)
```

But not with my input string:

```
In [4]: dateutil.parser.parse("28-05-2014_02:44:32.630", dayfirst=True)
...
ValueError: unknown string format
```

How can i define my own parser ?

Thk in advance !

---

(edit)

Here is my working code (thanks to roippi):

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

def my_date_parser(d):
    return datetime.strptime(d, '%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f')

i = pandas.read_csv('test.tsv', sep='\t', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=my_date_parser)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime.strptime` directly:

```
parseme = "28-05-2014_02:44:32.630"

from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(parseme, '%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f')
Out[34]: datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 28, 2, 44, 32, 630000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out `strptime` https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

The method definition is `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`

So we could use `datetime.strptime('28-05-2014_02:44:32.630', '%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%d.f')`

Not sure about the microsecond, you may been to strip that. You could use `'28-05-2014_02:44:32.630'.split('.')[0]` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for crate your parser !

```
import re
def my_parser(string):
 return re.split(r':|-|_',string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> s="28-05-2014_02:44:32.630"
>>> import re
>>> s="28-05-2014_02:44:32.630"
>>> re.split(r':|-|_',s)
['28', '05', '2014', '02', '44', '32.630']
```